# How can I know what object the for is printing in a dictionary in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have a dictionary that store associative arrays and is working perfectly, I´am using

```
sets[SaveNameOfSet]=WordsToSave //WordsToSave is a string array
```

And I know that if I need to iterate through the dictionary, I need to use this for:

```
 var value;
        for (var key in sets) 
        { 
        value = sets[key];
        console.log(set);
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML=value+"<br>";
        }
```

This shows me each element of every set, but it only prints me the last set, because I dont have the line jumper "\n" but in order for me to use it, I somehow need to know, in that for,what object (array) is printing of the dictionary so, How can I know that?
To finally show something like this:

```
Setnumber1:={1,2,3,4};
Setnumber2:={5,6,7];
```

Comment: Use `.innerHTML +=`, not `.innerHTML =`.

Comment: But how can I know the object that  the for(var key in sets) is printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a loop that goes through the sets. Each set is an array. You need an inner loop if you want to do something unique for each element in the set. Below is a sample that may help.

```
var value;
    for (var key in sets) 
    { 
    value = sets[key];
    setLen=value.length
        for (var j=0; j < setLen; j++) {
            var innerKey=value[j]; // this should get the inner array value [5,6,7] 5 is value[0], 6 is value[1], etc.
            // do something here to capture the inner action
        }
    ole.log(set);
    //document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML=value+"<br>";
    }
```